# Static Go binaries compiled on Linux 4.15.0 won't work on older Linux 2.6.18

Tags: go, compilation

I create a file named `hw.go` with the below code

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")
}
```

and compiled like this on ubuntu (pretty new version):

`go build -v -a -tags netgo -ldflags '-w -extldflags "-static"' hw.go`

Then I moved the binary to an older linux also 64 bit and while executing got this error:

what am I doing wrong ?

```
futexwakeup addr=0x558708 returned -38
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x1006 pc=0x425e5b]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x4becb7, 0x2a)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/panic.go:617 +0x72
runtime.sigpanic()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:374 +0x4a9
runtime.futexwakeup(0x558708, 0x2b1000000001)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/os_linux.go:81 +0x8b
runtime.notewakeup(0x558708)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/lock_futex.go:136 +0x44
runtime.startlockedm(0xc000000180)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:2105 +0x7e
runtime.schedule()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:2555 +0x69
runtime.park_m(0xc000000a80)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:2605 +0xa1
runtime.mcall(0x0)
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:299 +0x5b

goroutine 1 [runnable, locked to thread]:
internal/poll.init()
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x73
os.init()
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x54
fmt.init()
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x54
main.init()
        <autogenerated>:1 +0x45
runtime.main()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/proc.go:188 +0x1c8
runtime.goexit()
        /usr/local/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1337 +0x1
```

Comment: "to an older linux" is a bit vague. Just because you do not link libc does not mean any old kernel is supported.

Comment: compiled on an OS with kernel version 4.15.0 trying to execute on OS with kernel version 2.6.18, do you think this is the problem ?

Comment: I'm aware that minimum requirements for go is Kernel version 2.6.23 but I'm not trying to run go but a binary file that was compiled by go on a supported platform. I'm sure it's possible to run binaries that were compiled by go because I have some like this that's running on that OS, I just need to understand how can I compile to run on that old OS.

Comment: You _need_ at least 2.6.23 to compile and to run. This is a fact. You can try gcc or an _old_ version of Go. You cannot trick the actual Go compiler.

Comment: That is not an _old_ kernel, it is an _ancient_ kernel. No Linux distribution that used it is still supported, and hasn't been for many years. It is unlikely that you will be able to get any help for this. You should decommission the ancient machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tried an old compiler and it worked.
1.10.8 is the latest version it works, 1.11.8 doesn't work.

*I didn't check minor versions